# Embedding MonoTouch in an Objective-C iPhone program

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xamarin.ios, embed

I'm looking for some advice on calling C# methods from Objective-C on the iPhone. I've read the instructions at http://www.mono-project.com/Embedding_Mono along with numerous stackoverflow threads, but I'm still having problems. I can get everything to work on the simulator, but not on a device. At first, the call to `mono_jit_init()` failed with an assertion in one of the trampoline functions. Eventually I discovered that I had to do the following before calling `mono_jit_init()`:

```
const char *path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] UTF8String];
setenv("MONO_PATH", path, 1);
mono_jit_set_aot_only(YES);
```

Unfortunately, now I get the following error:

> Failed to load AOT module '/private/var/mobile/Applications/DD55C2F7-A692-4E68-B4DB-927690F9F3F2/DummyTest.app/mscorlib.dll.dylib' in aot-only mode.

Here's what I've done so far:

1. Run mtouch as follows:

   ```
   /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/mtouch --xcode=dummy --fat DummyLib.dll
   ```

   Note: This did not generate a main.m files as described in the documentation.
2. Copied the resulting DummyLib.dll, mscorlib.dll and DummyLib.dll.7.s files into my xcode project.
3. Added the following line to the "Header Search Paths" line in my xcode project configuration

   ```
   /Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/include
   ```
4. Added the following lines to the "Other C Flags" line in my xcode project configuration

   ```
   -D_THREAD_SAFE
   -DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1 -D_THREAD_SAFE
   ```
5. Added the following line to the "Other Linker Flags" line in my xcode project configuration

   ```
   -L/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/lib -lmono-2.0 -lpthread -liconv
   ```
6. Compiled and run my xcode project.

I'm sure I must be doing something wrong or I've missed a step somewhere, because other people claim to have this working. Does anybody have any idea what I've done wrong?

Comment: You can't dynamically load arbitrary dylibs on the device.  You need to statically link the library.